# SVNAnt Through Proxy

Tags: proxy, svnant

I just installed Ant for the first time today and have been playing with it. I am behind a proxy and I feel this is the source of my problems. I have managed to successfully create an ant build file which gets a web page over HTTP through a proxy without any problems. However, when I try to use SVNAnt to export a repository over HTTP through the proxy, I get "svn: HTTP proxy authorization failed" when the proxy task is exactly the same as in my Get build file. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

See [svn-proxy FAQ](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#proxy).